# Getting Image Style Properties in Word JS API

Tags: office-js

Is there a method to retrieve the image style properties of an embedded image inside Word using the JS API. Not seeing a method to retrieve an image style like "Beveled Oval, Black style" or an Artistic effect style such as "Paint Strokes"?

Answer (score 0):

The only API available is the [inlinePicture API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.inlinepicture?view=word-js-preview), but it does not have the properties you mentioned above: